# Bounds on constructors?

Tags: scala, macros, implicit

*NOTE: if someone can come up with a better title for what I am trying to ask - please mention or edit.*

Given a wrap method:

```
trait MyWrapperBound {
  val message: String
}

def wrap[T <: MyWrapperBound](message: String): T
```

I am looking for a way to describe that all all implementations of `MyWrapperBound` should have a constructor that takes a `message: String` so I can construct and return it from my `wrap` method.

I can think of a couple of ways to do this:

**Method 1 - using an implicit:**

```
def wrap[T <: MyWrapperBound](message: String)(implicit factory: String => T): T
```

This would mean that any `MyWrapperBound` impl. would also have to create the implicit:

```
case class SimpleBound(message: String) extends MyWrapperBound

object SimpleBound {
  implicit def factory(message: String): SimpleBound = SimpleBound(message)
}
```

This would result in a fair amount of boilerplate - which I'd like to avoid.

**Method 2 - macro:**

```
def wrap[T <: MyWrapperBound](message: String): T = macro ...
```

The macro would take the type, assert there is a valid constructor, constructing the type if its there and throw a nice compile error if not present for the developer to go and fix (by adding a valid constructor)

My question is - being fairly new to scala, is there a simpler option that I am missing? or another option that makes more sense?

Comment: Method 1 and method 2 are different things. In method 1 you talk about how you would implement it using an implicit and in method 2 you talk about how you would do validation using a macro. Did you mean to say you want to generate a constructor for the type using a macro in method 2?

Comment: Yes they are different ways of achieving the same goal. Method 2 would only validate and use the constructor if its already there. If its not there, it would be up to the developer to go and add it to remediate the compile-time error.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov - I've just seen the mistake I've made which I believe led to your comment. The macro version wasn't meant to have an implicit parameter....sorry for any confusion.

Answer (score 0):

If you're amenable to typeclasses there is a slightly simpler answer involving implicits. You can accomplish what you're trying to do rather easily by adding a type parameter to `MyWrapperBound` and enumerating the types of messages you'd like to support using the `Show` typeclass. For instance, if you knew everything that you were attempting to wrap supported a map `A => String`, you could supply a `Show[A]` implicit to your `wrap` method like so:

```
trait Show[A] {

  def show(a: A): String
}

trait MyWrapperBound[A] {

  val message: String

}

object MyWrapperBound {

  def wrap[A](a: => A)(implicit ev: Show[A]): MyWrapperBound[A] =
    new MyWrapperBound[A] {
      override val message: String = ev.show(a)
    }
}

object ShowInstances {

  case class MyDS(someInformation: List[String])

  implicit val simpleShow: Show[String] = new Show[String] {
    override def show(a: String): String = a
  }

  implicit val slightlyMoreComplexShow: Show[MyDS] = new Show[MyDS] {
    override def show(a: MyDS): String = a.someInformation.mkString("[", ",", "]")
  }
}
```

As always, the code compiles and produces the desired output. Adding more support is as easy as adding more instances to `ShowInstances`. This allows you to decouple the map `A => String` from the wrapper logic itself, so that `wrap` becomes a simple constructor for `MyWrapperBound`.

If you don't like the idea of parametrizing your `MyWrapperBound` with a type parameter, it's not even necessary if you're not planning to have instances of it indexed by some message type.